# Getting Started - Adaptive Parallel Payments

Tags: php, paypal, parallel-processing, payment

I need some help getting started with PayPal Adaptive Payments, it's the first time I'm using PayPal and I had no idea it would be this difficult, well at least for me.

I found this API integration code I'd like to use:
https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_parallel_payment/php?interactive=ON&env=www

I have downloaded the: PayPal PHP Adaptive Payments SDK

Basically I have an Index.php file with the code I found on the API Integration, what do I need to include on the index.php from the SDK to get this sample code running and working?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the samples from the GitHub repo and you can see what needs to be included.  Here's a [parallel payments sample](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/SimpleSamples/ParallelPay.php).

It looks like all you really need is...

```
require_once('../PPBootStrap.php');
require_once('../Common/Constants.php');
```

On a separate note, you may be interested in taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It's a lot easier to work with than PayPal's SDK, and I know a lot of PayPal integration specialists who actually prefer mine over their's as well.